# Unable to see USB attached drive in Samba

Tags: samba

1TB USB Drive formatted to exfat,
Ubuntu server 20.04.2 LTS.
Shared with Samba,
device added to fstab with "/dev/sda1 /srv/samba/share exfat auto noatime 0 0" but drive not appearing in the share.

No problem using raspian.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Hello Chris. Is the USB drive accessible to the server itself? Can you copy files to the drive when SSHing into the machine?

Comment: Your fstab declaration has the wrong syntax: there should be a comma between auto and noatime. Unless you have a complex install your OS is likely installed on /dev/sda1: I would use the UUID number for that USB partition instead - as in UUID=xxxx-yyyy. And by default that line would mount with owner=root who has write permissions but everyone else read only. Is that what you want?